# Pixelation during webkit animation in web app in Android device

Tags: android, animation, browser, webkit

I'm having an issue that whenever there is a webkit animation (i.e. translate3d) running in a web page in an Android device (2.2 or 2.3), all of the images in the page look pixelated. I've read that the reason for this is that the device goes into low-quality display mode the moment it detects an animation. Is there any way to prevent that? Or some way to make the images look better under those circumstances?

Thanks!

Comment: Just had the same problem. Couldn't get it to work, so fell back to animating `left` property.